# Mostrar nombres segun id

Tags: php, javascript, html

### a ver si me echan una mano con este pequeño problema, tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$sql="SELECT Nombre, fechaN, idU FROM detenido";
$res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


?>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      <?php 
        while($fila = $res->fetch_assoc()){
         echo "['".$fila['idU']."',".$fila['idU']."],";   
        }    
        ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Grafica de Detenciones'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Lo que busco es que en lugar de que aparezca el id en mi interfaz aparezca el nombre del registro guardado en mi BD espero y me puedan ayudar

Comment: si el idU viene de otra tabla relacionada puedes usar un JOIN

Comment: Hola @iBokii. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas

Comment: @mariovzc hice lo que me dijiste pero no se si este bien, espero y me puedas echar la mano: 

$sql="SELECT Nombre, fechaN FROM detenido INNER JOIN users on users.idU=Nombre.idU";

Comment: @iBokii el inner join que quieres utilizar quedaría $sql = 'SELECT Tabla1.Nombre, Tabla2.fechaN FROM Tabla1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON  Tabla1.idU = Tabla2.idU WHERE //aqui puedes agregar la condición que quieras'; aunque deberías de hacer caso al comentario que hizo Federico, porque no está entendible el código ni lo que quieres solucionar, espero te sirva.

Comment: @iBokii podrias arreglar las tablas y los campos que quieres cruzar?

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya logre unir las tablas.